# All Qt classes are highlighted with messages "Use of undeclared identifier" (Qt Creator from Xubuntu 20.04 repo)

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I installed Qt Creator from XUbuntu 20.04 repository using these commands:

```
sudo apt install qt5-default qtcreator qtbase5-examples qtdeclarative5-examples
```

And I got Qt Creator where all Qt classes are highlighted as errors with message "Use of undeclared identifier". But projects are compiled correctly. АUtocompletion of Qt Classes is also not working.
I don't want to install version from Qt site, because repo versions run faster.
Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The same situation presents on Kubuntu 20.04. But this problem does not exist on Debian 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it fixed by going to Help > About Plugins > C++ > uncheck ClangCodeModel.  Restart QtCreator.